# string.Format error with braces

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am trying build a string which have two parts of strings it errors out .....Here is my code below

```
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();          
            str.AppendFormat("{0}",GetAccessor(attr, rootTblName)).AppendLine();                
            str.Append("}").AppendLine();

            return str.ToString();


 private string GetAccessor(DataAttribute attr, string rootTblName)
        {
            return string.Format("get { return {0}.{1}; }", 
                GetRootPvtMember(rootTblName), 
                attr.MdlPart.InternalName
            );
        }
```

the error : input string format not valid.......
It fails i mean error out due to the "{" ,"}" in the GetAccessor return string with out them its working , but i need them like that . so any work around plz.....

Comment: You should accept one of the answers given below. I can also see you barely accepted answers in your previous questions, please do accept wherever is applicable.

Comment: i know its not allowing me to do within 11 mins from the question is asked , i tried

Answer (score 10):

Use double braces `{{` to escape curly braces in Format.

Comment: Suppose if the error message is coming from database, how can we escape with double braces. We can't update in the database because it is using in some other scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

Escape them with `{{` and `}}`.

Then it will work.

Eg:

```
string.Format("get {{ return {0}.{1}; }}", ....
```